# Not able to retrieve JSON response in my JSP

Tags: javascript, ajax, json, jsp, servlets

I have the following AJAX function,to be called after some JavaScript validation in JSP.  But I am not able to see the response of my AJAX request. I did some investigation using F12 developer tools, to check whether I am receiving the response body, I could see the response.

How do I read the response from the JSON object in JSP?

```
 $.ajax({
       type: "GET",
       url: "AjaxActionController?",
       dataType: "json",
       async : false,
       data:"leave_Type="+leave_Type,
       Success: function(data){
           alert(data);
           return_Leave = data.LeaveType;
           alert(return_Leave);
```

Comment: Check the url, dont't need the **?**

Comment: @Khanh  I am able to receive the request in my servlet, And as I pointed out in my question, I am able to see the response in response body of F12 developer.

Comment: `Success` should be `success` (lower case)

Comment: Thanks Khanh TO, it works fine now. Thanks for your immediate reply.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use "success" (not "Success").

Try this:

```
$.ajax({
   type: "GET",
   url: "AjaxActionController?",
   dataType: "json",
   data: "leave_Type="+leave_Type,
   success: function(data){
       alert(data);
       return_Leave = data.LeaveType;
       alert(return_Leave);
   }
});
```

**NOTE:**

- If the server sets the `Content-Type` header value to `application/json` then jQuery will automatically convert the response to a JavaScript object and you typically don't need to use the `dataType` property.
- I would recommend removing `async: false` so that the request is asynchronous. Synchronous requests are bad practice and you should avoid them. The end-user cannot interact with the page while the synchronous request is being handled by the server and the page will seem to be frozen.